# O que são SQL dialect 1 e o dialect 3?

Tags: sql, firebird

Não entendo muito bem com esses negócios de banco de dados mas me deixou curioso esses SQL dialect.

- O que SQL dialect?
- Qual é a diferença entre o SQL dialect 1 e o SQL dialect 3?
- E para que serve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O Firebird suporta 3 dialetos SQL tanto no servidor quanto no cliente. Estes se diferenciam no formato de date-time e precisão de números. Os dialetos servem para instruir o firebase server em como processar as funções em Borland Interbase legados, anteriores a versão 6.0. Dialetos são configurados em runtime e podem ser trocados pelo cliente no momento da conexão ou com o comando SET SQL DIALECT, tabela que ilustra as diferenças:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obs: Obs: Atualmente é possível somente criar bancos de dados no dialeto 1 e 3, sendo a versão 3 é a recomendada, pois a versão 1 será eventualmente descontinuada, o dialeto 2 não pode ser usado para criar bancos, pois ele só serve para converter o dialeto da versão 1 para a 3.

Fonte: https://firebirdsql.org/manual/isql-dialects.html

Answer (score 4):

Não tem a ver com SQL em si e sim com o Firebird. Em algum momento o produto concluiu que algo que ele fazia estava errado e decidiu fazer diferente, mas bem pouca coisa mudou. Mas muita gente estava acostumada com a forma antiga, tem códigos que se valem da forma antiga, então você pode ter formas diferentes dele atuar de acordo com sua necessidade.

Diferenças:

[image: Diferenças entre os dialetos do Firebird]

[Fonte](https://firebirdsql.org/manual/isql-dialects.html).

[Documentação](http://firebirdsql.org/manual/gfix-dialect.html).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).